# Invalid use of non-static member function c++ thread linux

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried run a function, which starts thread, but i recived error :

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Sniffer::f1(int)’
```

code:

```
#include "library.hpp"

class Sniffer
{
    void f1( int x );
    void f2();
};

void Sniffer::f1( int x )
{
    while (true)
    {
        sleep(x);
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
}

void Sniffer::f2()
{
    int y = 5;
    std::thread t1( f1, y );
    t1.join();
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any other way, to fix it without change a function, on static function?

Comment: Why don't you want to make it static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ member functions have an implicit first parameter that binds to `this`. When creating a thread, the `this` pointer must be passed. You must also qualify the member function with a class name. The correct thread constructor in your case would look like this:

```
std::thread t1( &Sniffer::f1, this, y );
```

Alternatively, you could pass a lambda to the thread constructor instead:

```
std::thread t1([this, y] // capture the this pointer and y by value
{
    this->f1(y);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create `std::thread` it doesn't capture the `this` pointer for you. You would have to include the `this` pointer when creating the thread, or you could use a lambda that captures `this` or captures everything by reference.

e.g:

```
void Sniffer::f2()
{
    int y = 5;
    std::thread t1(&Sniffer::f1, this, y);
    t1.join();
}
```

or:

```
void Sniffer::f2()
{
    int y = 5;
    std::thread t1([&,y](){f1(y); });   // captures everything (including this) by reference, captures a copy of y
                                        // becuase y coud go out of scope and be destroyed while the thread could 
                                        // continue running (even though in this case that won't happen because the join is in the same scope
    t1.join();
}
```

Of course, if you capture `this` then you don't need to mention it in the body of the lambda and without parameters needed we can remove the `()` which simplifies to:

```
void Sniffer::f2()
{
    int y = 5;
    std::thread t1([this,y]{f1(y); }); 
    t1.join();
}
```